# Cannot pull report metadata for analytics:reportChart filter

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I am using the  component in visualforce and need to build the filter attribute. Exported the 18 character ReportID from the dataloader. However, when I load the URL to describe the metedata for the report I am getting an error:

*INVALID_SESSION_ID Session expired or invalid*

This URL in order to build the filter for the visual force component: https://cs10.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/00OJ0000000e1P0MAI/describe

Here's the visualforce code: Ignore the column field name. This column filed name is what I am looking for.

```
<apex:page standardController="Audit__c" showHeader="true" > 
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="theGrid">
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e1R1" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" filter="[{column:'Audit_Name.Id',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]"/>
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e2FB" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" />
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e0o4" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" /> 

</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

This is the report. I need to filter the analytics:reportchart by Audit Name.

[image]

**SOLUTION:**  (Hopefully this will save someone time)

Using the  Apex component and Filtering
http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm

```
<apex:page standardController="Audit__c" showHeader="true" > 
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="theGrid">
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e1R1" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true"     filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]"/>
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e2FB" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" />
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00OJ0000000e0o4" size="tiny" showRefreshButton="true" />               
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Where:
filter="[{column:'Audit__c.Name',operator:'equals',value:'{!Audit__c.Name}'}]"/>

- Column value is the object name associated with the report column
- Operator is the comparison operand
- Value is what the column value must equate to.This can be a merge
  field, text, number……

**To find the column value do the following:**

- Open salesforce Workbench at :
  https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php
- Log into your salesforce or (test, production,….)
- Select ‘Utilities’ from the top menu
- Select  REST Explorer
- Click the Execute button
- Drill down to the ‘reportMetadata | detailColumns

The column value will be the name associated with the position (left to right) where the index starts at ‘0.’

[image]

Comment: Invalid session ID - May be the report url is incorrectly referring to a sandbox that is different than where you are testing?

Comment: I think this is a firewall issue. When I use IE the 'decribe' file downloads but cannot be opened or saved. Weird. I'll update the solution using workbench. Turns out you don't even need the 18 char Report ID.